# What happens inbetween clicking the button Submit and the method create in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I ask this because I have a form with a radio button set to nil :

```
 = f.radio_button :estimate_type, nil
```

I have debugger right at the beginning of my method call :

```
def create
  debugger
```

When I hit the debugger, I check out my params, and they say the value is `on` *not* `nil`.

Enter Insanity wolf. Somehow this is getting converted on click. And I've scoured the entire app looking for possibly a leaky javascript file, or anything closely resembling the word 'on'. I've checked all my bases. Defaults in schema.rb, jquery click events, model validations, you name it. Nothing with the word "on" anywhere.

So the real question is, is there a way I can throw a debugger in a place in which if I were to click submit, the debugger would appear *before* the model validation, and then hopefully where the params are still what they are in the form. And then I can follow it down the trail and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Most of the transformation of your params happens in the `ActionDispatch::ParamsParser` middleware, so it's going to be tricky to get at the raw params. But it's somewhere to start looking.

Comment: Thanks Emily, johnernaut, Ron, Frederick Cheung! You guys helped me out so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have anything to do with your JavaScript.  This is something that I've experienced before as well, but I'm not sure why it converts nil to 'on'.  I do know that passing in `:nil` as a symbol returns a null string, as well as just simply passing in `false`.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach to trying to solve your problem may be to put the debugger in the validation callback itself.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with rails - you could verify this by using your browser's network inspector to see that the browser is actually sending the parameter value "on".

By trying to set the value to nil (which doesn't really make sense - parameter values are always strings) you're suppressing the value attribute entirely from the generated HTML.

The [standard](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/common-input-element-apis.html#dom-input-value-default-on) says that in this case the default value for the input shall be "on" and so that is what your browser submits.